# VBA code inconsistently crashes Excel (run-time error 80010108)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following VBA code to automate moving a row on one sheet to another.  About 1/3 of the time, it gives a "run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)" and then crashes Excel.  I cannot find a common reason why.  After a crash, I can execute the same code on the same row, and it may or may not work fine the next time.

Can anyone tell why this code below should be unstable?

```
Sub Move_to_Sheet2 ()
'
' Move_to_Sheet2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Set Rng = Nothing
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveWorkbook.save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fully qualify your Rows. See this example.

```
Sub Move_to_Sheet2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet name
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        .Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Rows("4:4").Insert Shift:=xlDown
        .Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Delete
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: You should also qualify fully - eg  `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` otherwise if you're working in multiple instances of Excel it will fail. Also, it's ultimately better to work with `Codename` Eg `With Sheet1` so if anyone changes the Excel name of the sheet the code will still work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()

' Test Macro

    Range("A24:C30").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 10
    Range("A31").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("Save Sales").Select
    Range("B6").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Sheets("Invoice").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("B9").Select
    MsgBox "Print Now"

End Sub
```