# Excel VBA, run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method 'Insert' of object 'Range' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very simple code that just copies a column and inserts it. But occasionally running the macro would result in the above run-time error and crash Excel.

I'm hoping someone could tell me what I've done wrong.

```
Sub PushOutAWeek()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    With ws
        Set rng = .Columns(ActiveCell.Column)
        rng.Copy
        rng.Insert xlShiftToRight

    End With

    Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

When I click "debug", it highlights the following line as being the problem:

```
rng.Insert xlShiftToRight
```

Screenshot of the data I'm inserting new columns into:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KuFf.png)

Comment: Can you paste a Screenshot of your data where you are facing this Error, because as the code is, it should work fine.

Comment: @Mikku I've added a link to the screenshot, above.

Comment: On which column are you getting the Error ?

Comment: Any of them. There's no consistency. The macro can run perfectly fine for days, and then it'll give me a run-time error and I'll have to restart Excel to get things working properly again.

Comment: I think it is similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205033/vba-code-inconsistently-crashes-excel-run-time-error-80010108), but my VBA is not good enough to know how to fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might Work: Could be a possible error in setting the Range, this code will avoid it.

```
Sub PushOutAWeek()

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        .Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Copy
        .Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Insert xlShiftToRight
    End With

    Application.Calculate

End Sub
```

Comment: It all works, but since I can't control when the run-time error happens, I won't know for certain. I'll keep this thread updated if anything changes.
Thanks again @Mikku!

Comment: Sure No Issues .... Accept it as answer if you don't face any error for a while :)

Comment: I'm afraid it happened again, run-time error.

Debug says it's the `.Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Insert xlShiftToRight` line

Comment: Then you need to share the Sheet and tell me on which line it happened. Otherwise I don't see how to identify the issue.